# Externalize PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I have a bunch of figures made using Matplotlib's PGF backend. To avoid regenerating all these plots with Matplotlib if there is a style change, I prefer to just `\input` the PGF files directly in my document. This works fine, except it means arXiv disallows my 16 MB of sources.

Is there a way I can externalize the PGF files just like I would TikZ files? I'd really like to avoid regenerating all the plots, as this is quite time-consuming.

Comment: Does it help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271414/1952

Comment: @Ignasi: I don't think so, no. The linked question is about externalizing `\begin{tikzpicture}…\end{tikzpicture}`. I have pgfpictures, not tikzpictures.

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181125/pgf-externalize-with-list-and-make-on-windows?rq=1) help? I don't know if you are on Windows, but the general method doesn't seem to be OS dependant.

Comment: Have you checked [matplotlib2tikz](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz) ?

Comment: @Kpym: That project seems not to make much sense when Matplotlib has a first-class PGF backend…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround could be to generate a separate PDF with the `pgfpicture`s, one on each page, and replace the inputs with `\includegraphics`. The `standalone` class makes this easy, for example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\standaloneenv{pgfpicture}
\begin{document}
\input{onefigure.pgf}
\input{anotherfigure.pgf}
\end{document}
```

Save this as e.g. `figs.tex` and compile. In your manuscript, say `\includegraphics[page=1]{figs}` instead of `\input{onefigure}`, and similar for the others. Of course you could create one PDF per figure if that is preferable.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and wrote my own package to deal with it automatically. You can find it [here](https://github.com/dionhaefner/pgfcache). If you don't want to install the package, you can essentially put this code into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\edef\@figdir{_pgfcache}

\catcode`\#=11
\catcode`\|=6
\newcommand{\@basicpgfpreamble}[1]{%
    \unexpanded{%
        \documentclass{standalone}^^J
        \usepackage{pgf}^^J
        \let\oldpgfimage\pgfimage^^J
        \renewcommand{\pgfimage}[2][]{\oldpgfimage[#1]{|1/#2}}^^J
    }%
}
\catcode`\#=6
\catcode`\|=12

\let\@pgfpreamble\@basicpgfpreamble

\newcommand{\setpgfpreamble}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\@pgfpreamble}[1]{\@basicpgfpreamble{##1}\unexpanded{#1}}
}

\newcounter{@pgfcounter}
\newwrite\@pgfout
\newread\@pgfin

\newcommand{\importpgf}[3][]{%
    \IfFileExists{#2/#3}{}{\errmessage{importpgf: File #2/#3 not found}}%
    \edef\@figfile{\jobname-\the@pgfcounter}%
    \providecommand{\@writetempfile}{}%
    \renewcommand{\@writetempfile}[1]%
    {%
        \immediate\openout\@pgfout=##1%
        \immediate\write\@pgfout{\@pgfpreamble{#2}}%
        \immediate\write\@pgfout{\string\begin{document}}%
        \immediate\openin\@pgfin=#2/#3%
        \begingroup\endlinechar=-1%
            \loop\unless\ifeof\@pgfin%
                \readline\@pgfin to \@fileline%
                \ifx\@fileline\@empty\else%
                    \immediate\write\@pgfout{\@fileline}%
                \fi%
            \repeat%
        \endgroup%
        \immediate\closein\@pgfin%
        \immediate\write\@pgfout{\string\end{document}}%
        \immediate\closeout\@pgfout%
    }%
    \def\@compile%
    {%
        \immediate\write18{pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -output-directory="\@figdir" \@figdir/\@figfile.tex}%
    }%
    \IfFileExists{\@figdir/\@figfile.pdf}%
    {%
        \@writetempfile{\@figdir/tmp.tex}%
        \edef\@hashold{\pdfmdfivesum file {\@figdir/\@figfile.tex}}%
        \edef\@hashnew{\pdfmdfivesum file {\@figdir/tmp.tex}}%
        \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@hashold}{\@hashnew}=0%
            \relax%
        \else%
            \@writetempfile{\@figdir/\@figfile.tex}%
            \@compile%
        \fi%
    }%
    {%
        \@writetempfile{\@figdir/\@figfile.tex}%
        \@compile%
    }%
    \IfFileExists{\@figdir/\@figfile.pdf}%
    {\includegraphics[#1]{\@figdir/\@figfile.pdf}}%
    {\errmessage{Error during compilation of figure #2/#3}}%
    \stepcounter{@pgfcounter}%
}
\makeatother
```

This provides you with two commands, `\setpgfpreamble` and `\importpgf`. `\importpgf` does two things:

1. Checks whether a pre-compiled PDF version of the figure is already present in a folder called `_figurecache` (you might have to create this one). If so, it just includes that PDF with `\includegraphics`. If not, it calls `pdflatex` to compile the figure, then includes it. The figure is also re-compiled if the source of the figure changes (checked via the MD5 checksum of the file).
2. It patches the `\pgfimage` command inside your PGF figures, so you can include rasterized parts created with Matplotlib even if they reside in a subfolder (as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127667/matplotlib-pgf-images-in-subdirectory)).

You can use the command like this:

```
\importpgf{path/to/file}{myfigure.pgf}
```

With `\setpgfpreamble`, you can define additional packages that are needed to compile your PGF images (such as fonts or math packages):

```
\setpgfpreamble{%
    \usepackage{libertine}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
}
```

The only dependencies are the `standalone` and `pgf` packages.
The first compilation will take a long time if you have a lot of figures, but subsequent compilations will be much faster.

Caveats: It's probably not very portable (only works if you're using PDFLaTeX; the `pdflatex` executable must be on your path; and you have to compile with `-shell-escape`). Also, error-checking is limited, so if you run into trouble, check the logs in the `_figurecache` folder for errors (you might have forgotten to include a package with `\setpgfpreamble`).

Comment: This is pretty cool, but I notice that the written TeX files for the figures end up with spaces before the braces, which breaks compilation. Should the output be written with \string in a way or another?

Comment: Maybe you want to open an issue on the linked GitHub repository?

Comment: Thanks @Dion, I considered that, but as it only supports pdflatex I assume the difference in behaviour is due to that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hacky solution that probably will not work in any cases.
The idea is to replace `pgfpicture` environment with `tikzpicture` one, and then to use externalization.

For this you can :

1. read your file in a macro using `catchfile` package;
2. patch this macro using `patchcmd` from `etoolbox` to replace `pgfpicture` with `tikzpicture`;
3. put all this in a macro `\mypgfimport` that set `\tikzsetfigurename`.

Here is the code:

```
% ------------------------------------
% example file blablatest.pgf
\begin{filecontents}{blablatest.pgf}
\begin{pgfpicture}
\pgfpathsvg{M 0 0 l 20 0 0 20 -20 0 q 10 0 10 10
t 10 10 10 10 h -50 z}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{filecontents}
% ------------------------------------
\documentclass[border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{svg.path}
\usetikzlibrary{external}\tikzexternalize

\def\mypgfimport#1{%
  \tikzsetfigurename{#1}
  \CatchFileDef{\tempmacro}{#1.pgf}{}%
  \patchcmd{\tempmacro}{\begin{pgfpicture}}{\begin{tikzpicture}[red]}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\tempmacro}{\end{pgfpicture}}{\end{tikzpicture}}{}{}%
  \tempmacro%
}

\begin{document}
  \mypgfimport{blablatest}
\end{document}
```

[image]