# LaTeX matplotlib pgf shows no colorbar - instead shows colorbar png image filename

Tags: tikz-pgf, python, matplotlib

**Moved from Stack Overflow**

I'm producing various plots with matplotlib and save them as PGF files. These are then imported in my LaTeX file and compiled using the pgf package.

The problem is, I can't seem to render colorbars for some reason. Also web searches came up empty so far, as I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for in terms of bug.

I produce my plot like this

```
fig = plt.figure()
gs  = gridspec.GridSpec(10, 1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[:7, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[7:, :], sharex=ax1)

[...]

# plot
sc = *scatter plot of my data*
# colorbar
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(sc, cax=cax)
# save
fig.set_size_inches(8, 5)
plt.savefig('isotropy-raw.pgf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Then I get this

[image: File Output]

but upon including that in my tex file

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \input{path/to/file/isotropy-raw.pgf}
  \caption[x]{x}
  \label{x}
\end{figure}
```

it compiles this

[image: LaTeX Output]

I'm a bit baffled at this point. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Providing an MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \input{isotropy-raw.pgf}
  \caption{A nice caption}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[PGF File](https://nofile.io/f/sDRTyK6576C/isotropy-raw.pgf)

[PNG File](https://nofile.io/f/jeS4Y7bnCOk/isotropy-raw.png)

[Colorbar PNG](https://nofile.io/f/kkRYNP3yrvy/isotropy-raw-img0.png)

The colorbar png file is created by LaTeX upon compiling.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Are you able to share the `.pgf` and `.png` file?

Comment: @samcarter Thank you! I will provide the files and an MWE, give me a sec.

Comment: @samcarter done!

Comment: Thanks! I just tested and your code works fine for me ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vx5Q.png). Can you compile the little document from your question and share the .log file?

Comment: @samcarter here you go: [log](https://nofile.io/f/6eyKGBrZSXU/MWE.log)

Comment: OK, at the end of your log file it says `Package pgf Warning: File "isotropy-raw-img0.png" not found when defining image
 "pgflastimage". Tried all extensions in ".pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:" on input line 
44183.
)`

Comment: Can you test if `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{isotropy-raw-img0.png}

\end{document}` works?

Comment: I see that. What causes this if it compiles fine on your machine? In my case, the image is in a subfolder, that might be valuable information.

Comment: This wont compile, as it is in `/subfolder/isotropy-raw-img0.png`

Comment: I see, this explains the problem. Open `isotropy-ray.pgf` in a editor and replace `\pgfimage[interpolate=true,width=0.220000in,height=1.210000in]{isotropy-raw-img0.png}` by `\pgfimage[interpolate=true,width=0.220000in,height=1.210000in]{path/to/file/isotropy-raw-img0.png}`.

Comment: @samcarter genius! (if you put in the right subfolder) it works!

Comment: @samcarter now, that being a kind of dirty solution, any way to automatize this?

Comment: To automate maybe this thread could help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127667/36296